# Dropping Partitions in Vertica

Tags: partitioning, vertica, database-partitioning

I have a table like below in Vertica,

```
Seq_No  CO_NO   DATE
1       PQ01    01-Sep-15
2       XY01    01-Oct-15
3       AB01    01-Nov-15
4       PQ02    01-Dec-15
.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
14      XYZ9    01-Oct-16
```

And table has Partition by Month and Year based on the **DATE** column.

At any point of time there has to be only 13 partitions ie 13 months of data.
If the current months data comes in(Oct-16) then we need to drop last years SEP month partition(SEP-15) by keeping only 13 partitions on the table(ie Latest 13 months of data).

How can we achieve this in Vertica?

Answer (score 1):

To do this use the drop partition procedure

```
SELECT DROP_PARTITION('schema.table',CAST(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-13),'YYYYMM') AS INTEGER));
```

What you need is cron job that will run every beginning of the month.

Before drop all partitions prior to 13 manually and them let the job do it`s work.

Note: your table must be partitioned like :

```
PARTITION BY (((date_part('year', Datecol) * 100) + date_part('month', Datecol)))
```

- test the drop partition before using it, create a dummy table and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your focus is on the "At any point of time" part of your question. One of two solutions, I guess.

1. Add a script to your loading job that finds any partitions older than your threshold and drops them (look at the `partitions` system view, if you are trying to come up with a more generic approach you can extract the partition expression from the `tables` system view).
2. Instead of having to be on top of the partition drops, you could just create a view around your table and use that instead to only show the past 1 year of data.  Example:

   ```
   create view myview
   as
   select * from mytable
   where mydate >= current_timestamp - interval '1 year'
   ```

Or something similar, like `trunc(current_timestamp - interval '1 year','MM')`, etc. Then you can drop partitions at your leisure.